# How to print string from an int method without returning int?

Tags: java, queue

I am working on a method. It returns `int`.

```
int top() {
   return q.peek();
}
```

The method above works fine for non-empty queue. It is not for empty queue.

When I modify this code to handle empty queue, it will be like this

```
int top() {
   if (q.isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println("queue is empty"); // I want to end the process here 
      return -1; // I don't want this line to return -1
   }
   return q.peek(); // I don't want this line to execute
}

System.out.println(q.top());
```

The result will be like this if the queue is empty

```
queue is empty
-1
```

I want it to print only `queue is empty`, not -1.

So is there a way to modify only `top()` method for this case in Java?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the purpose of this? You are trying to print the return value of `top()` which returns `int`, and expect that to be a `string`. Why?

Comment: `Optional<Integer> top() { return q.isEmpty() ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(q.peek()); }`

Comment: This seems like a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What do you need to achieve here?

Comment: @TiDu Hi, thank you for your comment. I am requested to modify only `top()` method. I cannot modify `System.out.println(top());` even though I want to.

Comment: You could always just print the `q.peek()` from inside `top()` instead of where it is called from.  So you would have a `print` in the `q.Empty()` block and a `print` before the `return q.peek()`.  Though I agree this seems like an XY problem.

Comment: @Nexevis Yes, I can always print `q.peek()`. But it will not work with an empty queue. And if I remove `return -1;`, the code will print `queue is empty` and will go to `return q.peek();`. And this line will throw a `NullPointerException` error. 

So I'd like this method to end its process at `System.out.println("queue is empty")` without returning -1. 

I have also tried `try-catch`, but it doesn't work. So I ask, are there other ways to print only `queue is empty` in my code?

So sorry for my bad explanation.

Comment: If you cannot change the call of `System.out.println(q.top());` then the only possible solution i see would be to change the return type of the `top` method to return a `String` and then return a String representation of the number or your "Queue is empty" String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to change `System.out.println(q.top());` to a call to only `q.top();` you can simply just print from inside the method:

```
int top() {
   if (q.isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println("queue is empty");
      return -1;
   }
   System.out.println(q.peek());
   return q.peek();
}
```

---

If you are unable to change ANYTHING about the `System.out.println(q.top())` statement you would need to return a `String` instead and use `Integer.toString` to convert the value to a `String`:

```
String top() {
    if (q.isEmpty()) {
        return "queue is empty";
    }
    return Integer.toString(q.peek());
}
```

Comment: Yes, I cannot change `System.out.println(top());`. This would be the better way. Because `top()` should be able to reuse any time when dequeuing something from the queue and seeing its front. And also I don't want it to throw any exception.

Answer (score 2):

Are you wanting to print the int returned only if the queue is not empty, otherwise print "queue is empty"? If so, how about doing something like this:

```
int top() {
  if (q.isEmpty()) {
    return -1;
  }
  return q.peek();
}

System.out.println(q.top() == -1 ? "queue is empty" : q.top());
```

And another option:

```
int top() throws Exception {
  if (q.isEmpty()) {
    throw new Exception("queue is empty");
  }
  return q.peek();
}

try {
  System.out.println(q.top());
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When a method signature return `int`, you should not try to return another type as it can confuse other members who read your code.

If you cannot modify the `System.out.println()` method, the best option is to throw an Exception in your method like the answer given by Caitlyn Wiley.

Another acceptable way is to return an int that signify error (like you did with -1), as long as you have good docs to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found another way to solve this problem without changing `top()` data type.

```
int top() {
    if (q.isEmpty())
        System.out.println("queue is empty");
        System.exit(0);
    return q.peek();
}
```

What do you guys think?

I thank you every answer to my question. I am very grateful.
All answers are very useful.

Comment: This would halt the execution of the entire program after the queue is empty, which I doubt is an intended side effect.

Comment: You are right!!! This one will halt the entire program. That's why I gave you the right solution.

Comment: Question owner can also answer his question too. Thanks

Comment: Yeah of course, I just didn't notice you were the same person, my bad.